# Copying a table of files (stored as bytea) into individual files on disk?

Tags: bash, postgresql, shell, copy

using the COPY command in postgresql 8.4 to export data of type bytea, this would work fine for a single record:

```
copy (SELECT encode(test_column, 'hex') FROM test_table LIMIT 1) TO '/home/user/file.hex'
```

after that, i use the `xxd` command to obtain the appropriate file type.
sorry in advance if this is a very noob question, but is it possible to export all the records into file-1,file-2...file-n? what's the right syntax or script? i cant seem to find it in the man of postgresql copy.
for example, this is a bash script for a single row:

```
#!/bin/bash

psql \  
    -P t \  
    -P format=unaligned \  
    -X \  
    -U myuser \  
    -h myhost \  
    -c "select my_bytea_col from my_table where id=1" \  
    mydb \  
| xxd -r -p > dump.txt
```

however, i need to execute it on all ids and have them saved under different files each such as file1.txt, file2.txt, file3.txt.. etc..
what could also be very interesting is the ability to use another column's data (such as id) to name the resulting hex file accordingly.

Comment: This sounds like a job for a scripting language with a native PostgreSQL driver, like Ruby/Pg, Python/psycopg2, or Perl/DBD::Pg . You could probably shell-script it, but ... why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd use a scripting language with direct PostgreSQL support for this.

This does the job quite nicely given a database named `regress` containing a table called `files` with columns `fileid` (an integer) and `filedata` (a bytea). It writes the data to files in the directory specified by the `outdir` variable, in files named according to a pattern like `{filenameprefix}{fileid}{filenamesuffix}`.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import os
import sys
import psycopg2

outdir = "files"
filenameprefix = "f"
filenamesuffix = ""

def main():
        os.makedirs(outdir, exist_ok=True)
        conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname=regress")
        curs = conn.cursor();
        curs.execute("SELECT fileid, filedata FROM files;")
        for (fileid, filedata) in curs:
            fn = filenameprefix+str(fileid)+filenamesuffix
            f = open(os.path.join(outdir, fn), "wb")
            f.write(filedata)
            f.close()
        conn.close();

if __name__ == '__main__':
        main()
```

I used this code to create the test environment referred to in the above script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import psycopg2
conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname=regress")
curs = conn.cursor()
curs.execute('CREATE TABLE files(fileid serial primary key, filedata bytea);')
for i in range(1,10)
    curs.execute('INSERT INTO  files(filedata) VALUES (%s);', (psycopg2.Binary(open('/dev/urandom','rb').read(1024)),))
```

Edit: To make it the same as the naming you used in your question, which I just assumed was generic anonymized names, change:

- `regress` -> whatever your database name is
- `files` -> `my_table`
- `fileid` -> `id`
- `filedata` -> `my_bytea_col`

The equivalent to this script can be done in bash, it's just cumbersome. You'd need to use a co-process to do it in a transaction-safe way. You'd need to create a `psql` co-process and open a `SERIALIZABLE` transaction in it, then `SELECT fileid FROM files` into a shell variable. Loop over the shell variable and for each ID, `SELECT filedata FROM files` into the `xxd` pipe to a filename created with string interpolation on the ID.

IMO: Not worth the hassle, use a scripting language that gives you direct PostgreSQL access.

If you don't need it transaction safe it's a little easier; just fetch the IDs in one `psql` invocation, then the file data in subsequent ones. It'll be slower and won't be transaction safe but it'll be easier.

Comment: this looks like a very elegant solution. ive been fiddling with it for a while but im not really getting it, excuse the ignorance. can u help use the actual database and table and field names in the script so i can better understand on how to implement it? for example, the db is test_db, the table is test_table and the columns are test_id and test_data. why are we creating a table? im confused

Comment: @3a2roub I've provided the DDL for the test environment I set up when writing the script, so it's clear exactly how it was set up. Like you should've provided for your question - `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT` statements so everyone knows the table structures. You didn't provide them, so I had to make some up. Question edited to more clearly separate test setup data from the script to use.

Comment: @3a2roub I assumed that the table and field names you used in your question were just generic bogus examples, not something you were actually using. It's typical to anonymize to generic names in questions. I've added a mapping table to the answer to show you what's what in case it wasn't clear.

Comment: oh i get it im sorry i got confused from the setup at first. it's fine now, thanks a bunch!

Comment: @3a2roub No worries. Thanks for following up seeking clarification; *responding* is the most important thing on Stack Overflow, and what many people never really get the hang of. Thanks.